# TFS 2018, code search and work item search returns error: Unexpected error in search service

Tags: elasticsearch, tfs

I have upgraded to the `TFS 2018 PRE PROD` server migrating the `OLD TFS 2015` Update 3 databases from a Prod environment.

I have added an application tier server to the configuration, so i have two app tier. I have taken the secondary app server and configured the search feature.

The configuration is done using the `UI` of `TFS 2018`. The configuration seems to be ok as there was no error.

Now when I went and tried searching Work Items or Code i get the below error n whatever I search:

> There was a problem processing your request.   Unexpected error in
>   search service.

Do i need to do additional configuration post the search service configuration?

**Update**: I can see the below error in the application tier eventlog:

ExceptionType Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Search.Common.SearchPlatformException

Message Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Search.Common.SearchPlatformException: ElasticSearch Response is invalid ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() at Elasticsearch.Net.HttpConnection.Request[TReturn](RequestData requestData) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Search.Platforms.SearchEngine.Implementations.ElasticSearchPlatform.ValidateQueryResponse[T](IVssRequestContext requestContext, ISearchResponse`1 queryResponse, IEnumerable`1 requestIndices) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Search.Platforms.SearchEngine.Implementations.ElasticSearchPlatform.Search[T](IVssRequestContext requestContext, EntitySearchPlatformRequest request, EntityType entityType) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Search.Query.CodeSearchQueryForwarder.ForwardSearchRequest(IVssRequestContext requestContext, SearchQuery searchQuery, IEnumerable`1 indexInfo, IExpression scopeFiltersExpression, String requestId, DocumentContractType contractType) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Search.WebServer.CodeSearchControllerBase.HandlePostCodeQueryRequest(IVssRequestContext requestContext, SearchQuery query, Boolean isSecurityChecksEnabled, Boolean isCustomProjectSecurityCheckEnabled)

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether the **elasticsearch-service-x64** service is running on the server where Search is configured. If the service is stopped, start it and access the Search server again.

More details please refer to "**Search stops working and no results are shown**" section under "Troubleshoot Search in Team Foundation Server":

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/search/code/administration#troubleshoot-search-in-team-foundation-server

Comment: Dong, thanks for replying, i have checked the service seems to be running fine. Where are the errors logged for the search feature?

Comment: One thing i have noticed is that, the search URL is automatically configured as localhost and i cannot access from any other machine other then the server where it is configured.

Comment: You could type Search Service url when you configure Code Search/Work Item Search. Try to re-configure it.

Comment: When i configure for the first time and chose the install search services, it does not allow me to choose. but unconfigure and try to reconfigure has the option to provide the URL. But even if i provide a different URL, the search engine always gets configured with localhost:9200, at least that is what the search tab show in the Admin console.

Comment: Faulting application name: elasticsearch-service-x64.exe, version: 1.0.15.0, time stamp: 0x51543b9d
Faulting module name: jvm.dll, version: 25.71.0.1, time stamp: 0x59af5edd
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000216bc8
Faulting process id: 0x1bbb8
I have this error in the event log.

Comment: Have you followed "Unconfigure Search when its configured on a separate server" section in the link below to unconfigure Search? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/search/code/administration#unconfigure-search-in-team-foundation-server

Comment: Yes I tried that, once the search is removed i tried reconfiguring it, without any luck.

Comment: It seems there is an existing bug for Elastic Search filed at https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/15889, and the suggestion there is trying to upgrade the JVM. You could have a try.

Comment: i tried that, my java version is 8-152 and it does not work still. I the indexing is not happening due to some reason.

Comment: How about re-index the collection: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/search/code/administration#re-index? If re-index still not work, could you try on another machine?

Comment: I have tried that. After careful investigation on the application tier, i saw the error that is provided in the question.

Comment: It seems the error related to Elasticsearch, I've added Elasticsearch tag to see whether there is more help here.